# Copy formula from one cell to another using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I would like to copy-paste the formula from one cell to another using `openpyxl` with the transposition you usually get when you use Excel.

For example, copying the formula `=SUM(J3:J18)` to the next column would automatically change it to `=SUM(K3:K18)`.

I found this method that could work by using `win32com.client` but I don't know any equivalent for `openpyxl`.

Is there a way to do this using `openpyxl` or shall I manually replace all the column numbers using regex?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`openpyxl` provides (at least now) some tools to translate formulae via the `Translator` class. It is mentionned in the page related to formulae [tokenizer](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formula.html):

Here is an example on how to use it.

```
 >>> from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator
 >>> ws['F2'] = "=SUM(B2:E2)"
 >>> # move the formula one colum to the right
 >>> ws['G2'] = Translator("=SUM(B2:E2)", "F2").translate_formula("G2")
 >>> ws['G2'].value
 '=SUM(C2:F2)'
```

Here is the current prototype of the function for translating formula:

```
def translate_formula(self, dest=None, row=None, col=None):
    """
    Convert the formula into A1 notation, or as row and column coordinates

    The formula is converted into A1 assuming it is assigned to the cell
    whose address is `dest` (no worksheet name).

    """
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do this manually but you might want to look at using the [tokeniser](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formula.html) rather than writing your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jean Francois T. already provided the correct answer, which is derived from the openpyxl documentation.

The following approach is unambiguous on how to use the arguments. Also, it is more generic as it does not need literals hence it is practical inside a loop.

Suppose you want to copy the formula one column to the right from the source cell to the destination cell:

```
from openpyxl.formula.translate import Translator
source_cell = ws.cell(row=r, column=c)
dest_cell = ws.cell(row=r, column=c+1) # one column to the right
formula = source_cell.value
translated = Translator(formula, source_cell.coordinate).translate_formula(dest_cell.coordinate)
ws[dest_cell.coordinate] = translated
```

where the row index is `r=2` and the column index (for F) is `c=6`, if you consider the documentation example, but could be easily be the iteration variables of a loop.